# distribute play framework with editable views

Tags: playframework

Coming from an ASP.NET MVC background, I had gotten used to being able to edit views, scripts, and CSS files on the server after publishing. However, it appears that Play's dist command puts all of your content into a jar. This is extremely inconvenient if you need to edit something real quick on the server. Is there any way to edit content on the server without having to do something like compile the entire project server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly: no.

Play's views are compiled and fully type-safe, so if you need more dynamic templating you'd need to implement it yourself.

TIP: for development purposes Jenkins + SCP can help to reduce the efforts a lot.